# How to remove the particular array value in firebase

Tags: firebase

[I want to remove the particular array value in the list using firebase with ionic. I know that particular value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbb7D.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post a link to a picture of JSON data. Instead include the JSON as text in your question. Also include the code of what you've already tried, since similar questions have been asked before. Your case may well be different from those, but you're not providing enough information for us to go on.

Comment: Also, [avoid arrays in distributed data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase). You probably want to read the [Ionic guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html) and [the $remove method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-removerecordorindex)